# How can I create a user selection menu in commandline for Java?

Tags: java

I want to create a user selection menu like this for a simple math game:

```
=============================
Create a New User         [1] 
Continue as Existing User [2]
Exit                      [3]
=============================
```

When the user selects [1], the game will start, and when the user selects [2], then a list of users will be shown, something like this:

```
=============================
Select User to Continue As
John  [1]
Rob   [2]
Steve [3]

Back Button [0]
=============================
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: One thing, other than clicking, if the user types 1 the game creates a new user. That can be done pretty easily with the help of switch statements.

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;`  if your new try to google it

Answer (score 3):

1. Print instructions to user (Like this: `System.out.println("Create a New User         [1] ")`)
2. Take from console what user input (`Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   int menuItem = scan.nextInt();`)
3. Compare user's input with possible cases(`switch (menuItem):{case 1: //do your code; break; case 2: //do your code; break;}`)

Answer (score 1):

```
      //add code to accept choice
    System.out.println("\n============================="+"\nCreate a New 
    User         [1]"+
    "\nContinue as Existing User [2]"+"\nExit                      
    [3]"+"\n=============================");
    
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        
        //call method to create user;
        break;
    case 2:
         //call method to conitnue as existing user
        existingUser();
        break;
    case 3:
        //call method to exit
        break;
    }
```